# 5V Songle relay, pcb slightly hotter than room temperature

Tags: pcb-design, relay

On a self made pcb, I use a SONGLE 5V Relay, powered with 5V (datasheet: http://old.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/20084141716341001RelayX1.pdf ).

After some hour that relay is active, I can "sense" with the finger that PCB and relay itself is a couple of degree more hot than room temperature.

Attention: it is not hot, it works, doesn't burn, but with finger you can "sense" more heat.

'Cause on same PCB i have also a temperature sensor, is there a mode to eliminate that heat? I could adequate the sensor adjustemnt to -0.2°, but I'm looking for a more professional solution.

In production PCBs I see every time some cuts under the relay itself. I can imagine they are made to separate "high" voltage from "low" voltage. But maybe they serve for heat dissipation also?

This is the BRD, relevant on PCB part for relay:

[image]

Relay is soldered on bottom layer. If I need some cuts on the PCB, how you would do them?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You can replace the relay with a bistable (latching) type, but they are more expensive and most are designed for low power applications (2A or less). You pulse their coil to change the position.

The coil of the relay you have dissipates 450mW or 360mW nominally depending on sensitivity type. Often there will be other heat sources on a board of similar magnitude but that coil is a significant source, and of course it varies depending on state. The contacts and traces to the contacts are also a source of heat if the normally open or normally closed contacts are carrying current and that will vary with the relay state.

There may be other suppliers with similar parts that take less- if you don't mind changing the pinout the  [G6DN-1A DC5](http://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g6dn.pdf)  from Omron is only 110mW. You can also try to play games by reducing the voltage nominally or after the relay pulls in but if you actually need to operate over a  wide temperature range you may have issues (relays are actually current operated and the resistance of the coil increases with temperature so they are less likely to pull in with low voltage-- and electrical life may be compromised).

I doubt you'll seem much improvement from slots in the PCB but you can try. If it's a multilayer board you can try to heat sink the relay part and (of course) cut out any undesirable internal planes (but you should have done most of that anyway).

Putting a sensor on the board, as putting it on a chip, is not usually a good way to measure anything except the board temperature or die temperature respectively.

Hey, if you want a dumb idea for free- mount a resistor nearby and turn it on when the coil is off (LED dropping resistor or something). You could probably reduce the **change** in temperature rise by a factor of 4:1 over a modest temperature range.

---

On a different matter, you could get a bit more coil-contact creepage distance by running the coil traces straight back and necking them in at the diode. No big deal if it meets your requirements, but it could be better at no cost.

Comment: Or simply extend the sensor with wires and move it away from the PCB, if slightly changing the product design is an option.

Comment: @Dampmaskin I'm a big fan of putting the sensor on the an isolated section of the PCB with jumpers to the rest of the PCB and breaking the transition board off after assembly and testing.

Comment: YOu can also change the PCB footprint to add heat sinking fills with checkerboard or slotted solder mask to gather solder to bring up the heat transfer numbers. BUt if it is not a ventilated enclosure that will not help much.

Answer (score 1):

Temperature sensing is always prone to error when relying on convection air flow.

There will be an error difference from where air is free to move in the middle of a room and where it is restricted against a wall on a PCB and perhaps partially enclosed.  It is an unavoidable error and the heat mass of the wall adds latency to the detection but then  the heat source of the relay serves to raise the sensor temperature.

I think the easiest option is to position the sensor below the relay so that rising heat causes air flow from sensor towards heat and upwards.

e.g. **locate sensor near air intake on bottom of unit.**

### from datasheet

The standard Songle relay draws about 0.45W and the High sensitivity version draws about 0.36W.

### My Analysis

I imagine the relay controls some source of heat for air detected by sensor, so the relay heat might raise the sensor some unknown amount and if this rises above some hysteresis threshold would shut off early.

But considering the latency of warm air reaching the sensor this could be a good thing.   "Ancient" mercury-glass thermostats once had this feature of anti-hysteresis by heating up tracks underneath the coiled mercury glass switch.  So this relay heat of abt. 0.45W may do more or less the same thing.